# Taylor expansion with Gaussian perturbation

Tags: real-analysis, probability, reference-request, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Let's say I have a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for simplicity. Assume $f$ to be analytic (or can be represented by $n$th order Taylor expansion). I also have a random variable $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. Given $f(x + \epsilon)$, I can write:

$
\begin{align}
f(x+ \epsilon) = f(x) + f'(x) \epsilon + \frac{1}{2} f''(x) \epsilon^2 + \frac{1}{6} f'''(x)\epsilon^3 + \frac{1}{24} f''''(x) \epsilon^4 + o(\epsilon^5)
\end{align}
$

By taking the expectation, I have $\mathbb{E}[f(x + \epsilon)] = f(x) + \frac{1}{2} f''(x) \sigma^2 + ...$. Is there some name for these sort of analysis, where they study the Taylor series with Gaussian pertrubation? Any insights would be greatful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such Taylor expansions are indeed studied. Not only for "Gaussian perturbations" but for arbitrary random variables as well. There is even [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables) about this subject.