# Why the expected value of error Taylor series approximation around the mean is zero?

Tags: taylor-expansion, expected-value

I came across the following sentence in Paul Wilmott introduces quantitative finance.

... a random variable S (in our example the stock price), then ...
using a Taylor series approximation around the mean of $S$. Write
$S=\bar{S} + \epsilon$, where $\bar{S}=\mathbf{E}[S]$, so the $\mathbf{E}[\epsilon]=0$.

Here is my question, why is that $\mathbf{E}[\epsilon]=0$? Just because we assume this is an unbiased approximation?

Comment: I don't see any use of a Taylor series in the formulas you copied. Perhaps there is some explanation in the parts of the book that you didn't quote, or perhaps the words "Taylor series" are used incorrectly here.

Comment: It's indeed a Taylor series approximation.

Comment: A Taylor series approximation implies you have a Taylor series and have taken a finite number of terms from it. A Taylor series looks like $f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\cdots.$ What are $f$, $x$, and $a$ here? What would the term $\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2$ look like if you rewrote it in terms of the given terms?

Comment: An example where an actual Taylor series is used with a random variable: [Taylor expansion with Gaussian perturbation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3463338/139123). So there's a Taylor series, and there's a random $\epsilon,$ but $\epsilon$ is not an error term of any Taylor approximation arising from that Taylor series.

Comment: I should add that the author stops at 2nd order derivation, and around 0.

Comment: I just noticed that it literally says "a Taylor series approximation around the mean of $S$." That implies that $a = \bar S$ and that $x = a + \epsilon$ (so every instance of $x-a$ can simply be replaced by $\epsilon$). Evidently the function $f$, if it occurs, is described elsewhere. This means $\epsilon$ is part of the input to the approximation, not the output of the approximation. It has expectation zero due to the way it was defined, which is completely independent of whether the approximation is unbiased or even useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is true of any random variable with finite mean:

$$\operatorname{E}[S] = \operatorname{E}[\bar S + \epsilon] = \operatorname{E}[\bar S] + \operatorname{E}[\epsilon] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[S]] + \operatorname{E}[\epsilon] = \operatorname{E}[S] + \operatorname{E}[\epsilon],$$ therefore if $\operatorname{E}[S]$ is finite, $\operatorname{E}[\epsilon] = 0.$